# How to join multiple data frames using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, reduce

I want to `left_join` multiple data frames:

```
dfs <- list(
  df1 = data.frame(a = 1:3, b = c("a", "b", "c")),
  df2 = data.frame(c = 4:6, b = c("a", "c", "d")),
  df3 = data.frame(d = 7:9, b = c("b", "c", "e"))
)
Reduce(left_join, dfs)
#   a b  c  d
# 1 1 a  4 NA
# 2 2 b NA  7
# 3 3 c  5  8
```

This works because they all have the same `b` column, but `Reduce` doesn't let me specify additional arguments that I can pass to `left_join`. Is there a work around for something like this?

```
dfs <- list(
  df1 = data.frame(a = 1:3, b = c("a", "b", "c")),
  df2 = data.frame(c = 4:6, d = c("a", "c", "d")),
  df3 = data.frame(d = 7:9, b = c("b", "c", "e"))
)
```

**Update**

This kind of works: `Reduce(function(...) left_join(..., by = c("b" = "d")), dfs)` but when `by` is more than one element it gives this error: `Error: cannot join on columns 'b' x 'd': index out of bounds`

Comment: Can't you do `Reduce(function(...) left_join(..., other args here), dfs)`?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. Yes, I can! Feel free to write it as your answer

Comment: Hmm, actually, this breaks if `by` has more than one element. See update

Comment: How do you expect the function to know which columns to join on? This is not really what the *_join functions where designed to do. If all of the columns have a common ID column you can use then your update solves the issue. Otherwise you are going to have to specify by hand which columns to use for the join for each pair.

Comment: try purrr:reduce() instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's been too late i know....today I got introduced to the unanswered questions section. Sorry to bother.

Using `left_join()`

```
dfs <- list(
              df1 = data.frame(b = c("a", "b", "c"), a = 1:3),
              df2 = data.frame(d = c("a", "c", "d"), c = 4:6),
              df3 = data.frame(b = c("b", "c", "e"), d = 7:9)
         )

func <- function(...){
  df1 = list(...)[[1]]
  df2 = list(...)[[2]]
  col1 = colnames(df1)[1]
  col2 = colnames(df2)[1]
  xxx = left_join(..., by = setNames(col2,col1))
  return(xxx)
}
Reduce( func, dfs)
#  b a  c  d
#1 a 1  4 NA
#2 b 2 NA  7
#3 c 3  5  8
```

Using `merge()` :

```
func <- function(...){
  df1 = list(...)[[1]]
  df2 = list(...)[[2]]
  col1 = colnames(df1)[1]
  col2 = colnames(df2)[1]
  xxx=merge(..., by.x = col1, by.y = col2, , all.x = T)
  return(xxx)
}

Reduce( func, dfs)
#  b a  c  d
#1 a 1  4 NA
#2 b 2 NA  7
#3 c 3  5  8
```

Comment: just to note : I had to keep the "key" variables as the first column, because after merging they automatically become the first columns in the dataframe

Answer (score 9):

Would this work for you?

```
jnd.tbl <- df1 %>%
    left_join(df2, by='b') %>%
    left_join(df3, by='d')
```

Comment: Doesn't generalize very well (which seems to be the point of the question).

Comment: This would seem to be the best solution. It generalises quite well, in fact: if you want to join another table, just add one more line to the pipeline. The code would end up looking not too different from a SQL multiple-join query.

Comment: @HongOoi but the by= variable varies right? please check my answer on this

Answer (score 7):

Yet another solution:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

dfs = list(
  df1 = data.frame(a = 1:3, b = c("a", "b", "c")),
  df2 = data.frame(c = 4:6, b = c("a", "c", "d")),
  df3 = data.frame(d = 7:9, b = c("b", "c", "e"))
)

purrr::reduce(dfs, dplyr::left_join, by = 'b')
```