# Loop throughout unknown hierarchy R

Tags: r, hierarchical-data

I am looking for a loop throughout unknown hierarchy R (I only know the data when I request). For example 
I request the highest Hierachy and put them in a dataframe

```
id name
1  Books
2  DVDs
3  Computer
```

For the next step I want to loop into the books category so, I do a new request with the id(1) and get:

```
id name
11 Child books
12 Fantasy
```

Again now I want to look into the next parent catagory of Child books and do a new request for id(11)

```
id  name
111 Baby
112 Education
113 History
```

And so on:

```
id  name
1111 Sound
1112 Touch
```

On this moment I don't know how deep each hierarchy is, but I can tell it is different for each different category. On the end I would like that the data frame looks like this:

```
Id name      Id name          Id name       id name     id name
1  Books     11 Child books   111 Baby      1111 Sound  ...
1  Books     11 Child books   111 Baby      1112 Touch  ...
1  Books     11 Child books   112 Education etc.
1  Books     11 Child books   113 History   etc. 
1  Books     12 Fantasy       etc.
.................
2  DVDs      etc.
.................
3  Computer  etc.
.................
```

So I can extract the numbers of rows of the next hierarchy and repeat the row that number of times.

```
  df[rep(x,each=nrow(df_next)),]
```

But I have no idea how to loop over an unknown (and changing) i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a not so elegant solution:

(i) `subFn` is a custom function that split `id` based on different lengths:

```
subFn <- function(id){
          len <- nchar(id)
          tmp <- lapply(1:len, function(x)substring(id, x, x))
          names(tmp) <- paste0("level_", 1:length(tmp))
          return(tmp)
         }    

## example
subFn("1111")
$level_1
[1] "1"

$level_2
[1] "1"

$level_3
[1] "1"

$level_4
[1] "1"
```

(ii) create a list of data.frame, where the id is separated into different number of columns based on its length:

```
dat_list <- lapply(list(df1, df2, df3), function(x) do.call(data.frame, c(list(name=x[, "name"], stringsAsFactors=FALSE), subFn(x[, "id"]))))
```

(iii) Using `dplyr` left_join to join two frames at a time:

```
dat_list[[1]] %>% 
    left_join(dat_list[[2]], by="level_1") %>% 
    left_join(dat_list[[3]], by=c("level_1", "level_2"))

    name.x level_1      name.y level_2      name level_3
1    Books       1 Child books       1      Baby       1
2    Books       1 Child books       1 Education       2
3    Books       1 Child books       1   History       3
4    Books       1     Fantasy       2      <NA>    <NA>
5     DVDs       2        <NA>    <NA>      <NA>    <NA>
6 Computer       3        <NA>    <NA>      <NA>    <NA>
```

To prevent the lengthy and convoluted steps in left_joining multiple data.frame, here's a solution inspired by [How to join multiple data frames using dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344214/how-to-join-multiple-data-frames-using-dplyr)

```
func <- function(...){
   df1 <- list(...)[[1]]
   df2 <- list(...)[[2]]
   col <- grep("level", names(df1), value=T)
   left_join(..., by = col)
  }

Reduce( func, dat_list)
```

Input data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:3, name = c("Books", "DVDs", "Computer"))
df2 <- data.frame(id = 11:12, name = c("Child books", "Fantasy"))
df3 <- data.frame(id = 111:113, name=c("Baby", "Education", "History"))
```